# Skip null or empty object to be assigned to an array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In case of mongoose find() or findOne() returned value is [] and null respectively, if where conditions are not true. And this returned value is getting assigned to the array but I dont want it to happen. Currently, I am performing filterMessage() to skip all the null values from the array but this is not the ideal way in case of large number of messages. Here is the code:

```
async media(receiverId, page, size, callback) {
    var promises = [];
    var groupMessageMaps = await GroupMessageMap.find({
        groupId: receiverId.toString()
    });
    groupMessageMaps.map((groupMessageMap) => {
        var message = Message.findOne({
            $and: [{
                _id: groupMessageMap.messageId
            }, {
                'type': {
                    $in: ['image', 'video', 'doc']
                }
            }]
        }); //if Message.findOne() is null then not push to the array
        promises.push(message);
    });
    var messages = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(messages); //contains null values also
    messages = this.filterMessage(messages).reverse();
    if (messages.length < size) {
        callback(messages);
    } else {
        messages = messages.splice(messages.length - size);
        callback(messages);
    }
}
```

So is there any way to skip [] or null to be assigned to the array messages by line promises.push(message).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `filterMessage` method use a trick to remove all `falsy` values from array of messages. As below:

`messages =  messages.filter(Boolean)`

Falsy Values include:

```
false
null
undefined
0
NaN
''
""
```

> Read more about falsy values at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: I have already tried it. Just before promises.push(message), I had used if(message) then do promises.push(message). But still pushing the null (if message is null).

Comment: No you can't do it just before promises,`Message.findOne`  returns a promise object not the returned value, at that message contains a promise object and your `if ` condition is always true. 

Use it on the place where you used `this.filterMessage`